# Map proxy model to source model index unexpected behaviour

Tags: c++, qt

There is a `QTableview` that has a `QSortFilterProxyModel` as its data backend. Each row in the table has a unique ID, but only in the source model (column 0), not in the proxy model. I need to iterate over all the rows of the table and find the row with a specific ID to identify a row to select. However `mapToSource` fails, as soon as I change the current index that I iterate over. Error: `QSortFilterProxyModel: index from wrong model passed to mapToSource`.

This behaviour is really odd because just before the for loop I do check if mapToSource works, and it does!

What Qt complains about is `if (proxy_index.model() != q_func()) {...}`, but I do not see why `q_func()` should all of a sudden return a different model...

```
    QModelIndex indexOfItem;

    QAbstractItemView *itemView = this->viewHandler()->currentView();
    QSortFilterProxyModel *m = static_cast<QSortFilterProxyModel*>( itemView->model() );
    qDebug()<<"proxy model:"<<m;
    qDebug()<<"source model:"<<m->sourceModel();
    int idColumn = static_cast<int>(MyEnums::ResourceDataFields::Common_uuid);

    QModelIndex startIdx = itemView->currentIndex();
    qDebug()<<"start index proxy model:" << startIdx;
    qDebug()<<"start index source model:" << m->mapToSource(startIdx); // <== OK!

    for ( int row = 0; row < m->rowCount(); ++row ){

          // Get index of next row to compare:
//        QModelIndex proxyIndex = m->index( row, 0 );
//        QModelIndex proxyIndex = startIdx.sibling( row, startIdx.column() );
        QModelIndex proxyIndex = startIdx.model()->index( row, startIdx.column(), startIdx.parent() );
        qDebug()<<"proxy index:"<<proxyIndex; // <== seems OK!

          // Map to parent model, to get ID column:
        QModelIndex sourceRow = m->mapToSource( proxyIndex ); // <== Error!

        QModelIndex idx = sourceRow.sibling( sourceRow.row(), idColumn );
        QString id = m->data( idx ).toString();
        qDebug()<<"id:"<<id;
        if ( id == uuid ){
            indexOfItem = m->index( row, 0 );
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( indexOfItem.isValid() ){
        qDebug()<<"Setting current index:"<<indexOfItem;
        itemView->setCurrentIndex( indexOfItem );
        itemView->scrollTo( indexOfItem );
    }
```

Comment: While I can't help you with the current problem, as you code does indeed look like it should work, wouldn't it be a lot easier if the proxy model would also just have the ID column?

Comment: Ha, yes, that is what I was trying to do then. But somehow hiding that column then (and others) did not work. So there are some other problems...

Comment: Hmm, strange, hiding the column(s) should be just a view things.
Alternatively you could modify the source model to have the ID as an additional role, independent of the column